# Alternate way of Squaring a Number

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I came up with this technique a few years ago. It seems to be working fine.

Input: a number

Output: Its' square

```
x=int(input("Enter the number whose square you wish to find out: "))  #decimal input invalid
last_digit=x%10
#We will use formula Sn= (n/2)*(2a+ (n-1)d) of AP
a=100 + last_digit*20 #100,20 are fixed values
d=200 #200 is a fixed value
n=(x-last_digit)/10

final_answer=(n/2)*(2*a + (n-1)*d) + last_digit**2 #These calculations are easier than x*x for a vvlarge x
#normal multiplication is d*d digits, but this is d*(d-1) or d*(d-2) digits

print("My answer:     " ,format(final_answer,'f'))
print("Actual answer: ", x**2)
```

I have written comments to indicate what Im doing at each step

-> How does this work? Like seriously? I got this by observing some patterns and generalising them
-> This code was meant to work only for 3-digit numbers, but it works for all numbers. How?

By expanding/substitution, my 'derivation' is as follows:-

NOTE: L=last_digit

n = (x-L)/10   #The same thing as n=x//10

a = 100 + 20L

d = 200

Our final answer is:-

=> (n/2) * (2a + (n-1)d ) + L^2

Substituting values for the variables,

=> [(x-L)/20] * [200 + 40L + [(x-L)/10]*200 - 200] + L^2

Taking the 20 in [(x-L)/20] and taking it to the RHS of * sign,

=> (x-L) * [10 + 2L + x - L -10] + L^2

=> (x-L)*(x+L) + L^2

=> x^2 - L^2 + L^2

=> x^2

Comment: Expand the terms and simplify. You'll end up with x^2. It's tedious but straightforward.

Comment: It may help to express `n` as `(x-last_digit)/10`.

Comment: Yes, I got x^2 in the end. @user2357112

Comment: Is there some past mathematical theorem about this, or why this works or is this just a coincidence that this works?

Comment: How big are the numbers you've tested this with?  I think that for very big numbers (the only ones alternative squaring arrangements would help with), you should start to be worried about the imprecision of the floating point numbers introducing error.  (Or just trying to store a too large number)

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what's happening

prabhat@Prabhat-PC:~/Desktop$ python3 my_Square_function.py 

Enter the number whose square you wish to find out: 10100100011

My answer:      102012020232202207232.000000

Actual answer:  102012020232202200121

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not giving correct output for 10 to 19 and 
it's only give correct output when x//10 is multiple of 2 because of this expression `(n/2)*(2*a + (n-1)*d) + last_digit**2` has `n/2`. 
and for rest of test cases it is giving approximate answer.
and Expand the terms and You'll end up with `x^2((2*last_digit/x) + 1)` and now it's obvious why those magic numbers were giving correct output .

Comment: 1) You said that you were getting x^2((2*last_digit/x) + 1) after expanding. However, I got something different.
Read the update in the question for my proof. Please point out any mistakes

2) I donot see why n/2 is a problem

3) "it's only give correct output when x//10 is multiple of 2". Try inputting 10000000000000000000 , 2222222222222222222222 and observe output

Comment: put n = x/10 you will get same answer as mine. and your computer don't calculates expression after minimizing it so n/2 does affect.

Comment: n=x/10 is incorrect both mathematically (Eg. 183 != 183/10) and in terms of programmng (183/10=18.3 and not 18 - it will be converted to a float value). Try putting input as 100000000000000000000. Here, n=x//10 = x/10 = (x-last_digit)/10. Here, also it is giving error in answer. The code is giving incorrect answer for all large numbers(odd and even)

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is failing for large numbers. I tried it only for integers and here is the list of some integers where the result differed-

> 94906267
>   94906269
>   94906271
>   And so on...

An interesting thing to note here is all the numbers which are creating the problem are odd.

Comment: Can you give some more context to your answer?  What "list" are you taking about?

Comment: By 'list', Archit means 'examples of values' and not list as in array. Archit, the code is giving incorrect answer for even values as well - try giving inputs with 4-5 more digits